# MySQL using MATCH AGAINST for long unique values (8.0.27)

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, fulltext-index

I have a situation where we're storing long unique IDs (up to 200 characters) that are single TEXT entries in our database. The problem is we're using a FULLTEXT index for speed purposes and it works great for the smaller GUID style entries. The problem is it won't work for the entries > 84 characters due to the limitations of innodb_ft_max_token_size, which apparently cannot be set > 84. This means any entries more than 84 characters are omitted from the Index.

Sample Entries (actual data from different sources I need to match):

```
AQMkADk22NgFmMTgzLTQ3MzEtNDYwYy1hZTgyLTBiZmU0Y2MBNDljMwBGAAADVJvMxLfANEeAePRRtVpkXQcAmNmJjI_T7kK7mrTinXmQXgAAAgENAAAAmNmJjI_T7kK7mrTinXmQXgABYpfCdwAAAA==
```

AND

```
<j938ir9r-XfrwkECA8Bxz6iqxVth-BumZCRIQ13On_inEoGIBnxva8BfxOoNNgzYofGuOHKOzldnceaSD0KLmkm9ET4hlomDnLu8PBktoi9-r-pLzKIWbV0eNadC3RIxX3ERwQABAgA=@t2.msgid.quoramail.com>
```

AND

```
["ca97826d-3bea-4986-b112-782ab312aq23","ca97826d-3bea-4986-b112-782ab312aaf7","ca97826d-3bea-4986-b112-782ab312a326"]
```

So what are my options here? Is there any way to get the unique strings of 160 (or so) characters working with a FULLTEXT index?

What's the most efficient Index I can use for large string values without spaces (up to 200 characters)?

Comment: Is there more than one token per row, and that's why you were using FULLTEXT? Or does the 200-character token appear as the only content in that TEXT entry? If the latter, then why not use a conventional (B-tree) index, not FULLTEXT?

Comment: Well, it's a combination of different "unique identifiers" from multiple external systems, so some entries could be GUIDs (or even in some cases 2-3 GUIDs in an [] array format), and others long crazy strings like what I shared above. We defaulted to FULLTEXT because originally it was just GUIDS, but now with these values, it seems another Indexing type may be required.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like there's a one-to-many relationship to the identifiers. I suggest one token per row, even if you have to create a new table so you can store multiple rows per entity. Then define a conventional index for the token column in that table.

Comment: Is that long string in a column by itself?  Or part of a large `TEXT` column?

Comment: So I added two more data samples showing the types of unique identifiers we store. Basically they come in three flavors. The long crazy strings, GUIDs, or a JSON array of GUIDs. @BillKarwin I don't think the 1 token per row is necessary because we already have that except for the GUIDs in the JSON arrays surrounded by quotes - I think the question is: which index am I stuck with, or what index method should I use for these 3 forms of unique data indexing in the same table?

Comment: @RickJames the values are stored in their own column that's indexed.

Comment: If you store the set of identifiers as a JSON array (even when there is only one identifer), and you are using MySQL 8.0.17 or later, you could use a [Multi-Valued Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued).

Comment: Thanks for the idea @BillKarwin I was thinking about that, but 90% of the entries are non-JSON. Sadly we're storing the Unique Identifiers from multiple external systems, so we can't really control what's being sent to us - the JSON is the rare instance where two GUIDs come from a system. From what I can tell, MATCH AGAINST won't work with this combination of IDs due to the length > 84. I guess I'll just revert to a BTREE solution?

Comment: A B-tree index can't help you find entries when there are multiple id's in a JSON array. All I can suggest is what I would do: transform the format of the entries after you receive them from the external sources, then store them in a consistent format, either as a JSON array, or as one value per row, which is how one-to-many attributes are customarily stored. I don't have any suggestion for how to index "anything" that you get from the external sources.

Comment: @BillKarwin I can get rid of the array and just have one entry per column setting (that's just a single string with no structure), but they could be up to 200 characters in length. Is BTREE the only solution for such data, and what speed issues might I encounter when I get 1M+ records?

Comment: @BillKarwin it's sad, what's really killing me is the enforced max length of @@innodb_ft_max_token_size, which is 84 currently. I don't know why they removed the ability to make this a larger value (previous versions allowed up to 252). If I could set this to 200, everything we have would work perfectly fine :(

Comment: Correct, you can't use the fulltext index for such long tokens. B-tree is the only other type of index supported by InnoDB. If you can use an index, the performance will be as good as you can make it. One million rows should still have acceptable performance, but I don't know what your requirements are. MySQL indexes can support much larger numbers of rows and searching is still quick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244004/discussion-between-floobinator-and-bill-karwin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a summary of the discussion in comments:

The id's have multiple formats, either a single token of variable length up to 200 characters, or even an "array," being a JSON-formatted document with multiple tokens. These entries come from different sources, and the format is outside of your control.

The FULLTEXT index implementation in MySQL has a maximum token size of 84 characters. This is not able to search for longer tokens.

You could use a conventional B-tree index (not FULLTEXT) to index longer strings, up to 3072 bytes in current versions of MySQL. But this would not support cases of JSON arrays of multiple tokens. You can't use a B-tree index to search for words in the middle of a string. Nor can you use an index with the `LIKE` predicate to match a substring using a wildcard in the front of the pattern.

Therefore to use a B-tree index, you must store one token per row. If you receive a JSON array, you would have to split this into individual tokens and store each one on a row by itself. This means writing some code to transform the content you receive as id's before inserting them into the database.

MySQL 8.0.17 supports a new kind of index on a JSON array, called a [Multi-Value Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued). If you could store all your tokens as a JSON array, even those that are received as single tokens, you could use this type of index. But this also would require writing some code to transform the singular form of id's into a JSON array.

The bottom line is that there is no single solution for indexing the text if you must support any and all formats. You either have to suffer with non-optimized searches, or else you need to find a way to modify the data so you can index it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new table 2 columns: a `VARCHAR(200) CHARSET ascii COLLATION ascii_bin`  (BASE64 needs case sensitivity.)
2. That table may have multiple rows for one row in your main table.
3. Use some simple parsing to find the string (or strings) in your table to add them to this new table.
4. `PRIMARY KEY(that-big-column)`
5. Update your code to also do the `INSERT` of new rows for new data.

Now a simple BTree lookup plus Join will solve all your plans.

`TEXT` does not work with indexes, but `VARCHAR` up to some limit does work.  200 with ascii is only 200 bytes, much below the 3072 limit.